# How to increase what the array prints everytime it runs

Tags: java

public String[] timesTables(int number, int delimiter) {
   int[] number ={1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};

int[] delimiter = {1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};

System.out.println(number[3] x delimiter[0]);
   }
that's what my code looks like right now. I not sure how to increase what the delimiter reads each time. For example right now its delimiter[0] but the next time it runs I want it to go to delimiter[1].

Comment: Sounds like you need a [`for-loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're using the 2 parameters for or what values are you passing into those, but if they are the index values of what you need from both the arrays, then use those instead of hardcoding the index.

```
public String[] timesTables(int number, int delimiter) {
    int[] numberArray ={1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int[] delimiterArray = {1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    System.out.println(numberArray[number] x delimiterArray[delimiter]);    
}
```

Are you invoking this method from a loop? If yes, probably pass the loop counter as a parameter and use that as the index for the array delimiter.

```
public String[] timesTables(int number, int delimiter, counter) {
    int[] number ={1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int[] delimiter = {1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    System.out.println(number[3] x delimiter[counter]);    
}
```

If you're not using a loop at all, the only other option(ugly) would be to use a static variable and use that as a counter.

```
static int counter = 0;
public String[] timesTables(int number, int delimiter) {
    int[] number ={1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int[] delimiter = {1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8};
    System.out.println(number[3] x delimiter[counter++]);    
}
```

The counter++ operation would increase the value of the counter every time it is used. The variable would hold it's value till the application is up. Once you restart the server, the counter would reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to get next delimiter. Based on question I assume you need to print number[3] * delimiter[0],number[3] * delimiter[1], and so on. You can use for loop for number array and delimiter array like below to print all the values.

```
for(int i=0;i<number.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<delimter.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(number[i] x delimiter[j]);
        }
    }
```

But what is reason behind number and delimiter int parameters of timesTables method? either you can expect 2 arrays by caller or just remove those.